# what is the difference between Task based asynchronous pattern and Event based asynchronous pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, concurrency, reactive-programming

Both the patterns seem similar to me. In both the patterns, a persistence mechanism is involved which stores the **events** in case of Event-based asynchronous pattern and **tasks** in case of Task-Based asynchronous pattern.
Secondly, both the patterns involve a manager which keeps track of what is happening with each event or tasks. I couldn't find any differences between the two. Help explain.

Comment: **Depends on specifics**, but in a very general sense I'd argue that "Tasks" are usually waited on directly (ie. there is a "complete" or "failed" handler directly on the Tasks/Futures/Promises that can be attached to drive the next action), while "Events" are signaled from / as part of "another object" (ie. a single event source might support many different events such as "KeyPressed" or "ButtonClick"). And then proper "Reactive" programming is neither of the above :}

Answer (score 3):

from Petri Net point of view, both tasks and events are tokens. The computation proceeds as follows: events are added to tasks just as arguments are added to a function call. When all arguments/events are collected, the transition fires and the task is executed. While running, the task emits other events and tasks.

That is, actually there exists only one, task-event model, which is usually called either event or task model, for brevity.